# psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "sso_server_consumer" does not exist

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, psycopg2

I am working on implementing Django-Simple-SSO to our python based platform. I am following this blog to implement SSO:

https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/django-single-sign-on-sso-to-multiple-applications-64637da015f4

This code is the step number 3 on the server side of django-simple-sso.

```
    from simple_sso.sso_server.models import Token, Consumer

    Consumer.objects.create(public_key='your_application_public_key', private_key='your_application_private_key', name='your_application_name')
```

**psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "sso_server_consumer" does not exist** -- this is the error I am getting as soon as I run the above code in django shell. Can someone please help me on how  to solve this error?

I have run both `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands. But, still getting the same error.

I am able to see the `Consumers` table in the django-admin page under the heading `SSO_SERVER`. But, when I click on that `Consumers` table, I  am getting this error page  :

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/sso_server/consumer/
relation "sso_server_consumer" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "sso_server_consumer"
```

And also why is that `Token` imported? As it was not used anywhere in that sso blog post.

Thank you

Comment: did you run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: yes I ran both the commands..

Comment: In `psql`  does `\d` show the table? Or maybe is it named differently e.g. different casing?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver is there a way to check, which database my django platform is using? I am new to django. Right now I know only about the admin page which shows tables. I don't know how to use this ``psql`` command on my dango platform. And also I am not sure whether my platform is using postgreSQL.

Comment: You will need to find the settings file in your project and look at the settings for `DATABASES`. `psql` is a Postgres client, that comes with Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

The same happened with me. My mistake was that I didn't run migrations after integrating postgreSQL. After setting up the postgreSQL database, run these two commands:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

After making changes to the models, you want to run these two commands again:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```

It worked for me, Hope it works for you.

**ALL THE BEST!!!**

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the tables needed for Django-Simple-SSO do not exist in the database.

If you have added the packaged to your environment and installed the app, this is most likely because you have not made and applied migrations. Do so with the following:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

Then the tables will exist when the program goes to look for them.

Comment: yes I ran both the commands. But still getting the same error

Comment: Is it in your installed apps? Can you see your database and see if the tables were made? I'm willing to bet something is not going right with your migrations. If you are using Heroku, remember you *must* makemigrations locally, commit the migrations to git, and then migrate on the server.

Comment: Yes Hayden. I am able to see the ``Consumers`` table in Admin Page under the heading ``SSO_SERVER``. But, when I click on that , ``ProgrammingError at /admin/sso_server/consumer/``. I have added this complete error in my question above. Thanks

Comment: @saikrishna so you can see it in the Admin page, but can you actually see the tables in the database? I'm still convinced it's because the table `sso_server_consumer` does not actually exist in your database.

Comment: I am sure that this table is not properly created. Is there a way to check database tables of my django platform from terminal/GUI other than from admin page which django provides?

Comment: @saikrishna yes you can connect to the database directly. Where is your app hosted? You'll need database credentials and then you connect to it using something like `DBeaver`